# angular2 path is not recognised by system.js

Tags: angular

I had a working angular2 app while it was in alpha version. when i updated to 2.00-beta.0 i got errors

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:9090/src/angular2/angular2 404 (Not Found)     system.src.js 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:9090/src/angular2/angular2(…)addToError @ system.src.js:43linkSetFailed @ system.src.js:644(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:440.......
```

When i googled I found out that we have to set path in system.config.

```
System.config({'map': {
'rx': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.3/rx.js'
},
'paths': {
'*': './app/*'
 }
```

But this dosent work for me.Any solutions.

Comment: Can you post your SystemJS config?

Comment: Have you tried using `packages` in System.config ?
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: @TheKojuEffect System.config({
              packages: {
                  app: {
                      format: 'register',
                      defaultExtension: 'js'
                  }
              }
          });
          System.import('app/app')
                  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));